# Evaluating $\int e^{\sin x}\ dx$ in terms of a Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals

NOW before anyone gets too hasty in saying "oh, it's impossible," I would like to presume that it is possible despite the fact that it obviously is not, and theoretically search for some way of simply representing the solution. I came up with the idea of switching $e^{\sin x}$ into its taylor series and integrating every term. Now I have a new series, but how do I "de-Taylor" this series into some combination of elementary functions? Is this even possible with $e^{\sin x}$? Even if it isn't, is there a method for being able to de-Taylor a series? My equations:
$$
\int e^{\sin x}\ dx = x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{40}-\frac{x^6}{90}-\frac{x^7}{1680}\dots
$$
Surely there is some algorithm that satisfies those denominators, right? There just has to be! And of course, I know how naive this may seem to pursue, but I have taken an interest in this problem and am actively seeking a solution.

Comment: See [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we agree that the solution to our integral is of the following form:

$$\int e^{\sin(x)}dx=f(x)e^{\sin(x)}+C$$

For some $f(x)$.  Differentiating both sides reveals that

$$e^{\sin(x)}=[f'(x)+f(x)\cos(x)]e^{\sin(x)}$$

Which becomes equivalent to solving

$$1=f'(x)+f(x)\cos(x)$$

Furthermore, we can assert that $f(x)$ is not an algebraic function, since the LHS of this is algebraic while the RHS would end up being transcendental.

Indeed, the above differential equation was not able to be solved by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%3Dy%27%2Bycos(x)), so I highly doubt of a closed form.

Answer (score 1):

To get the power series for
$e^{\sin x}$,
you can do this:

Let 
$f(x) = e^{\sin x}$.
Then
$f'(x) 
= \cos x\,f(x)
$.

Therefore,
if
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n
$,
then
$f'(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_n x^{n-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1) a_{n+1} x^{n}
$.

Since
$\cos(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=\cos(x)f(x)\\
&=(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!})(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n)\\
&=(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!})(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2 \rfloor} (-1)^k \frac{1}{(2k)!}a_{m-2k}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2 \rfloor} (-1)^k \frac{a_{m-2k}}{(2k)!}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$(n+1) a_{n+1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (-1)^k \frac{a_{n-2k}}{(2k)!}
$.

Since
$f(0) = 1$,
$a_0 = 1$.

Then,
with $n=0$,
$a_1
=1
$;
with $n=1$,
$2a_2
=a_1
=1
$
so
$a_2 = \frac12$;
with $n=2$,
$3a_3
=a_2-a_0/2
=\frac12-\frac12
=0
$;
with $n=3$,
$4a_4
=a_3-a_1/2
=0-\frac12
=-\frac12
$
so
$a_4 = -\frac18
$.

So 
$f(x)
=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+...
$.
Integrating,
$\int f(x)
=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{40}+...
$.

This agrees with Wolfy
(there is an error in
your coefficient of $x^5$ -
you divided by 4 instead of 5).

Note that method
(which is not original by me)
can be used to get
the power series for
$e^{g(x)}$
where $g(0) = 0$:
let
$f(x) = e^{g(x)}$.
Then
$f'(x) 
= g'(x)e^{g(x)}
=g'(x)f(x)
$.
Substituting power series
for $f$ and $g$,
we get a recursion
for the coefficients
of $g$
in terms of the
coefficients of
$f$.

Read generatingfunctionology
(it's free!)
at
https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html
for lots more neat stuff.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be what the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah, this successfully shows how I got where I am. Thanks for that, but How can I now express that series as a new function, even just a generalized summation?

Comment: @dsillman2000 I'm looking for that algorithm.  Its somewhere XD

Comment: It's just a bunch of coefficients. I strongly doubt that there is a general form for them.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly simplify series form of that:

$\int e^{\sin x}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n}x}{(2n)!}~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}~dx$

$=\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n}x}{(2n)!}\right)~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}~dx$

For $n$ is any natural number,

$\int\sin^{2n}x~dx=\dfrac{(2n)!x}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}x\cos x}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}+C$

This result can be done by successive integration by parts.

For $n$ is any non-negative integer,

$\int\sin^{2n+1}x~dx$

$=-\int\sin^{2n}x~d(\cos x)$

$=-\int(1-\cos^2x)^n~d(\cos x)$

$=-\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^nC_k^n(-1)^k\cos^{2k}x~d(\cos x)$

$=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}x}{k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$\therefore\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n}x}{(2n)!}\right)~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}~dx$

$=x+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{x}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}x\cos x}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}x}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}x\cos x}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}x}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

If you still insist on its Taylor-series form, you can have this procedure:

$\int e^{\sin x}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n}x}{(2n)!}~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}~dx$

$=\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n}x}{(2n)!}\right)~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{C_n^{2n}}{4^n(2n)!}~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^mC_{n+m}^{2n}\cos2mx}{2^{2n-1}(2n)!}~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^mC_{n+m+1}^{2n+1}\sin((2m+1)x)}{4^n(2n+1)!}~dx$

(according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae)

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x}{4^n(n!)^2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^m\sin2mx}{4^nm(n+m)!(n-m)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^m\cos((2m+1)x)}{4^n(n+m+1)!(n-m)!(2m+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x}{4^n(n!)^2}+\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=m}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m\sin2mx}{4^nm(n+m)!(n-m)!}-\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=m}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m\cos((2m+1)x)}{4^n(n+m+1)!(n-m)!(2m+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x}{4^n(n!)^2}+\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m\sin2mx}{4^{m+n}m(2m+n)!n!}-\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m\cos((2m+1)x)}{4^{m+n}(2m+n+1)!n!(2m+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x}{4^n(n!)^2}+\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{m+k}2^{2k+1}m^{2k+1}x^{2k+1}}{4^{m+n}m(2m+n)!n!(2k+1)!}-\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{m+k}(2m+1)^{2k}x^{2k}}{4^{m+n}(2m+n+1)!n!(2k)!(2m+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x}{4^n(n!)^2}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{m+k}2^{2k+1}m^{2k+1}x^{2k+1}}{4^{m+n}m(2m+n)!n!(2k+1)!}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{m+k}(2m+1)^{2k}x^{2k}}{4^{m+n}(2m+n+1)!n!(2k)!(2m+1)}+C$

Answer (score -4):

There is no such thing as "de-Taylor". This integral can't be combined of elementary functions. Believe me because it's one of the simplest and most famous integrals that can't be combined of elementary functions. In fact only a small minority of integrals and taylor series have a presentation with elementary functions.

Comment: This is not true.  You can set up complicated DE and attempt to solve.

Comment: Did you contribute to the -3 rating of my answer because you thought I am wrong? And in your own answer you admit that I am right? I find this extremely unfair.

Comment: No where in my answer do I propose that it is impossible to undo a Taylor series.  Indeed, I downvoted because this question shows a lack of effort and is also not true.  How do you define "only a small minority of integral and taylor series have a [representation] with elementary functions"?  And even if true, it is like saying "most numbers are irrational, so the answer is most likely false".  Clearly, this needs improvement.